# Feedparser : insert in pg if does not exists

Tags: python, postgresql, feedparser

I got several issues on this one.
So I'm trying to use feedparser and psycopg. Probleme is, i don't want to have duplicated data.

```
    def dbFeed():
conn_string ="host='localhost' dbname='rss_feed' user='postgres' password='somepassword'"
print ("Connecting to dababase\n ->%s" %(conn_string))

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    print ("Connected!\n")
except:
    print ('Unable to connect to the database')


 feeds_to_parse=open("C:\\Users\\Work\\Desktop\\feedparser_entry_tests_world.txt","r")


for line in feeds_to_parse:
    parser = fp.parse(str(line))
    x = len(parser['entries'])
    count = 0   
    while count < x:
```

Now i have several solutions.
At first, i tried this :

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO feed (link, title, publication_date, newspaper) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)",
        (parser['entries'][count]['link'], parser['entries'][count]['title'],
        parser['entries'][count]['published'],parser['feed']['title']))
```

But of course i had duplicated data. So i saw this post here :
[Avoiding duplicated data in PostgreSQL database in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415884/avoiding-duplicated-data-in-postgresql-database-in-python)

And i tried this but I had a tuple index out of range error

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO feed (link, title, publication_date, newspaper) SELECT %s, %s, %s, %s WHERE NOT EXISTS
              (feed.title FROM feed WHERE feed.title=%s);""",
            (parser['entries'][count]['link'], parser['entries'][count]['title'],
            parser['entries'][count]['published'],parser['feed']['title']))
```

But anyway, that's not the way i want to do it. I want to add a condition in my while loop that tests the existance of the data before inserting, because i don't want to test the whole database, i want to test last entries only. Once again, of course it does not work, because i guess that  parser['entries'][count]['title'] is not what i think it is...

```
while count < x:
    if parser['entries'][count]['title'] != cursor.execute("SELECT feed.title FROM feed WHERE publication_date > current_date - 15"):

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO feed (link, title, publication_date, newspaper) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)",
        (parser['entries'][count]['link'], parser['entries'][count]['title'],
        parser['entries'][count]['published'],parser['feed']['title']))




conn.commit()

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add second title that is used in where part, also you can add extra conditions there:

```
cursor.execute(
    "INSERT INTO feed (link, title, publication_date, newspaper) "
    "SELECT %s, %s, %s, %s WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM feed "
    "WHERE title = %s AND publication_date > current_date - 15);",
    (parser['entries'][count]['link'],
     parser['entries'][count]['title'],
     parser['entries'][count]['published'],
     parser['feed']['title'],
     parser['feed']['title']))
```

Comment: I think the last line should be replaced by parser['entries'][count]['title'] because i'm testing article's names. Anyway it seems to work except for 3 newspapers... Thank's!